# Word search string manipulation

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, printing

This segment of code I have is part of a much larger code, but this segment what it basically does is the searchword(); function uses strstr to find all words matching to the users input search word puts the initial position of the word into the keywordsat[] integer array so that I can use it to the print 1 line of the text. what searchword(); returns is just number of words found or 0 when no words are found, dosent have word. printsummary() and wordfoundYN are irrelevant for this code bit. Also bear in mine message[] is a paragraph, with `\n` and stuff.

So basically this code currently functions properly, it finds key words within the message[] array and returns the starting positions of the words, puts them into keywordsat[]. Then in order to print only 1 line I go back until previous `\n` character then i simply print till the next `\n` character, thus printing out the line of the paragraph the word is contained in.

But I have a problem, lets say we assume that `message[]={"\n the cat is in the bag.\n"}`
and then the user inputs the search for word to be "the" it would print the same line in the paragraph twice, since it found the word in the sentence twice, keywordsat[] would fill up with 2 numbers keywordsat[0]=1 and keywordsat[1]=16. I was wondering if there was anyway for this program to know that if 2 words are in the same line, dont print the same line twice?

```
...
                searchwordYN=searchword();
                    if(searchwordYN!=0){
                        printsummary(d);
                        wordfoundYN++;
                        counter=0;
                        while(counter<searchwordYN){
                                i=keywordsat[counter];
                                while(i>=0){
                                    if(message[i]=='\n'){
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    i--;
                                }

                                for(f=i+1;f<10485760;f++){
                                        if(message[f]=='\n'){
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    printf("%c", message[f]);
                                }
                                printf("\n");
                                counter++;
                        }
                        counter=0;
                    }
...
```

My searchword() function:

```
int searchword(){
    char *ret;
    int i=0;

    ret = strstr(message, keyword);
    if(ret==NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    while(ret!=NULL)
    {
        keywordsat[i]=ret-message;
        i++;
        ret++;
        ret = strstr(ret, keyword); 
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: One problem is you have too many levels of indentation for comfort.  You should look to refactor your code into smaller functions.  There are 6 levels of indentation in the first fragment alone, and it looks like it might be at 3 or 4 levels of indentation before you get to that code.  Scary!  Hard to manage accurately, too.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to save the last position of start of line (value of i)

something like this might work:

```
  searchwordYN=searchword();
  if(searchwordYN!=0){

      //old start of line needs to be initialized by something bigger than file size 

      int oldStartOfLine = 10485760 + 1;

      printsummary(d);
      wordfoundYN++;
      counter=0;
      while(counter<searchwordYN){

          i=keywordsat[counter];
          while(i>=0){
              if(message[i]=='\n'){
                  break;
              }
              i--;
          }
          if( i != oldStartOfLine ){

              // only do the print out if this is a new line.

              for(f=i+1;f<10485760;f++){
                  if(message[f]=='\n'){
                      break;
                  }
                  printf("%c", message[f]);
              }
          }
          printf("\n");

          // save old start of line
          oldStartOfLine = i;
          counter++;
      }
      counter=0;
  }
```

At the end a tip:

Don't be afraid to use attributes to functions instead of using global variables. Makes it nicer.